# How to show only seven days from now in UIDatePicker in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

I need to show only seven days from now. How to achieve this using UIDatePicker and how we set minimum and maximum dates to UIDatePicker. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking, for example, how to set the minimum to be *today* and the maximum to be *7 days from today*?

Comment: Yes @christopherdrum.

Comment: Do you want to show seven days and minimum,maximum date?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
[datePicker setMinimumDate:[NSDate date]];
[datePicker setMaximumDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60*60*24*7]];
```

He wants only seven days including current date.

Comment: Thanks @Saraswati. And same like this is it possible for minimum time and maximum time like morning 10 AM to evening 6 PM. Is it possible ?

Comment: Saraswathi try to give detailed answer.

Answer (score 3):

A small caution against overly simplistic addition of time: simply adding seconds can encounter edge cases against daylight savings time transitions (for example). It is always a good idea to use NSCalendar to help manage time calculations.

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
calendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
NSDate *endDate = [calendar dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay value:7 toDate:today options:0];
```

The resulting endDate in the above code will be one hour different than simply adding seconds, in the case of daylight savings time occurring during the 7 day period. That one hour could break across a day change, causing a (rare) edge case failure.

Answer (score 0):

Set Min and Max date in the datePicker:

```
[datePicker setMinimumDate:[NSDate date];
[datePicker setMaximumDate:[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*7]];
```

Comment: Delete your answer.Already accepted answer is there.If you post the answer it should be unique.